# Unexpected memory allocation by malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc

here's a code that allocates some memory and copies a string into it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
int main(){
   char *t ="your_char";

   char *s = (char*)malloc(9);
                                                                                                                                    
   memcpy(s,t,9); 

   printf("%s\n",t);
   printf("%s",s);
   return 0;
}
```

now the output is

```
your_char
your_char☺╚
```

And that is what I am unable to understand. If I change to `memcpy(s,t,10)`, then there is no garbage value at the end.

I assume it is because of null terminator that also gets copied in second case. **But why is there an empty place at all** when I have only allocated 9 bytes and they are already occupied by the characters I copied.

Comment: C strings have a zero byte that marks the end of the string. So `"your_char"` takes 10 bytes when you count the zero byte, and you need to `malloc` 10 bytes, and copy all 10 bytes. Otherwise, `printf` doesn't know where the string ends. `printf` has no way of knowing the number that you passed to `malloc`. All it does is look for the zero byte to know where the string ends.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the code will fail if you overrun the allocated space, any more than you get arrested every time you break the law. You got away with it today but might not tomorrow. There wasn't an "empty place": there was no competition for it *at that moment* and it happened not to break anything.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you saying that when the string gets copied, if its size exceeds the allocated size then the remaining characters will be stored in the very next address (because there was no traffic at that place)?

Comment: The processor does what it is told to. If it breaks something, the task fails, and if it doesn't, the mistake can go unnoticed. If you stick to the language rules, then you don't risk failure.

Comment: @WeatherVane To clarify, in the above code, the null terminator didn't get copied. But why is there a garbage value at the 10th byte and why is there a 10th byte at all.

Comment: Because there was no nul terminator copied, when you tried to print the string, the processor continues to print whatever it finds until one of two things happens: it finds a random 0 in memory, or it tries to read memory that it is not allowed to read.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for this info and that clears the cloud. I additionally wanted to ask whether only printf searches for these or others like memcpy also do that. I did an experiment by creating another pointer c, allocating memory to it, then `memcpy(c,s,9)` and adding a printf for c at end. I noticed that the garbage values at the end of outputs of both c and s are same. so this means memcpy also searched for '\0'.

Comment: No, `memcpy()` copies exactly the number of bytes you tell it to. It does not search for anything. Whatever is in the next bytes, was already there, by chance.

Comment: @WeatherVane but its happening again and again. why don't you copy my code - then add `char *c = (char *) malloc(9);` in beginning, add `memcpy(c,s,9);` under the previous memcpy and add `printf("\n%s",c);` at last. You will see the garbage values are same for s and c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225374/discussion-between-mr-loop-and-weather-vane).

Comment: Trying to read beyond the end of the allocated memory has *undefined behavior*. The worst form of undefined behavior is the program doing just what you expected it to do (because you still have a bug but it's going to be hard to detect). The behavior may be either consistent or inconsistent. You can't draw any real conclusions from seeing it behave the same way twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is a **null terminated array of characters** (a "null character" is the one that has the numeric value of 0). The null character marks the end of the string, If an array doesn't have a null character in it, it is not a string. In particular, you cannot `printf` it with the `%s` specifier, because `printf` has no idea where it ends.

String literals always have one automatically, for example, `"your_char"` has **ten** characters in it and not nine. If you allocate strings dynamically, you should always account for the extra character.

Comment: you are right that `"your_char"` has 10 characters but I only allocated 9 bytes to `s`. If I had done `char *s = (char *)malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char)+1)` then it may have mattered but I manually specified 9 bytes then how is `s` pointing towards 9 bytes+empty byte.

Comment: run this code :  
 char tabstr[] = "your_char";
 printf("size in bytes of tabstr:%d",sizeof(tabstr));

Comment: @mr.loop "s pointing towards 9 bytes+empty byte" No, it doesn't. You only allocxated 9 bytes, so that;s what `s` points to. There is nothing beyond these 9 bytes.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  Oh! so the garbage value is not at the 10th byte but because of the absence of null terminator. Right?

Comment: mr.loop What s points to is a linear memory address where you can modify at most 9 consecutive chars. Any modification by you before or after that 9 chars is a violation the malloc() contract and MAY get you in trouble.

Comment: yeah you are right I should write `malloc(10)`

Comment: @mr.loop  you should not only allocate 10 characters, but also copy 10 characters.